# 'Customers from [country]' or 'Customers in [country]'?

Tags: prepositions

The latest line on Amazon.com

[image]

I wonder the use of *in* there instead of *from*. Am I missing something?

Does Amazon wants to *restrict* the base of clientele from India? Having this said, it's addressing the customers **already in India** and not all Indians **who want to become the customers of Amazon?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**If** Amazon would be a physical store in, say, the UK, they would welcome customers *from* India.

A web store can do the same thing, but for any (potential) customer, it doesn't matter at all where they *come from*, but *where they are* at the time of the purchase.

I don't think Amazon is aiming at welcoming Indians outside India, because they are very unlikely to be wanting to pay in rupees.

At the same time, if I were living in India, I would be a customer *from* the Netherlands, but *in India*, and I would be interested in the possibility to pay in rupees.

In short, they use *in* because they *are* targeting people in India, not Indian nationals.

Answer (score 2):

Concurring with Oerkelens; is this a helpful example?

I have a lodger **from** India, but he lives with me **in** England.  So, he pays me in Pounds Sterling; I wouldn't accept his rent if he wished to pay in rupees.

Amazon's use of **in** seems entirely correct and appropriate.  Only a presumption that everyone **in** a country is **from** that country should lead to confusion, but I suppose it was a natural enough assumption at first glance.

Comment: Wow I could have never thought of it like that way +1